# How to validate range of long in .NET 2.0?

Tags: .net, validation, .net-2.0

I found a solution to validate `Long` value using extra lib file '`vjslib`' as below. I must add another reference DLL file named vjslib.dll.

I know there is some method like `Int32.TryParse()` something for Int type validate. But I can't find `Long.TryPase()` directly.

Can anybody help me to find another easy way to validate it with only .NET default lib file?

Appreciated for your input in advance.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using java.lang;

namespace DataTypeValidate
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String value = "1F";

            long min = 0x0;
            long max = 0xFF;

            long n = Long.parseLong(value, 16);

            bool ok = (n >= min) && (n <= max);
            System.Console.WriteLine(ok);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "validate the range of long"?

Comment: I assumed there is a long value or no-long value(like bool, short int values) input by user. I need reject the non-long type value. That's why I need validate the input value. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for either `Int64.TryParse()` or `long.TryParse()`.  There is no such `Long` type.  (The `long` keyword is a C# alias for the `System.Int64` type.)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried something like

```
long n = Int64.Parse(value, NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

Have a look at

[Int64.Parse Method (String, NumberStyles)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkw23d3e.aspx) and

[NumberStyles Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles.aspx)